# How to fix "SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesize" in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I want to write a program to find sum of squares with a number as input. If i gave 5 to my code it should return (0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2=55).

```
sum(list(map(lambda x:i**2 for i in range(x+1),5)))
```

But i have an error like this.

```
sum(list(map(lambda x:i**2 for i in range(x+1),55)))
            ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Comment: I don't know why you didn't try parenthesizing it, then. But even if you did, you'd get another error, because you can't iterate over the integer 5. I have no idea how this code is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `map`

```
sum(i**2 for i in range(x + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Guy mentioned, if you are just after cumulative sum then following block of code would be enough

```
sum(i**2 for i in range(x+1))
```

The `map` function return an iterator from passed in expression/iterator. So let say, if you want to iterate over squares of numbers from 0..5 then following will return 0, 1, 4, 9, 16 and can be used to iterate with the help of `for loop`

```
    result_iterator= map(lambda x: x**2, range(5))
    for i in result_iterator:
        print(i)
```